# how to send a parameter from an html page to another with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, web

so I have two tables in my database Student and Computer
I have home.html page that contains a list of students retrieved from the database and when I click on the edit button I want to send the id of the chosen student to another html page so can display in it the list of computers that belongs to the student ( I know i can do it the same page but my training supervisor wants me to do it this way I have no choice ) 
Ps: I'm  using Spring boot and RestAPI for the the back-end and Angularjs for the front-end

Comment: Angular 1,2 or 4?

Comment: if your training supervisor has a specific way that they want the pages handled, why haven't they told you how they expect it to be done?  there are multiple ways to handle this, such a using cookies or session, sending the data to the server for the new page request, embedding the data in URL parameters, etc..  It's impossible to know which way will work in your situation, without seeing any code.

Comment: Actually I did it with sending the id through URL and then I made a service that retrieves it because I need that id in many controllers but she didn't like it. she wants it to be done in another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In angular 1, you can use services or cookies .

Cookies :
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Services :
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services